# jquery - click event

Tags: jquery

In the lightbox i render form containing textbox and buttons (next and prev).

Problem is, after i edit content in textbox and click "Enter button" it should fire click event on "next" button so that it takes to next form in lightbox

I used following code, but it is refreshing entire page instead of focusing "next" button alone.

And it gives error: `ActionController::MethodNotAllowed  Only get requests are allowed`

```
$("input").bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       $("#nextbtn").click();
    }
});
```

please correct if any thing wrong with the syntax

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return false` and call `preventDefault` on the `event` object in order to prevent submission of the form.

```
$( 'input' ).bind( 'keyup', function( e ) { 
    if( e.keyCode == 13 ) { 
       $( '#nextbtn' ).click(); 
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
```

} );

Also, change your `method` attribute to `GET`, the error is stating that you cannot submit `POST` requests.

Comment: page is still loading with this code..

so it take to error: 
ActionController::MethodNotAllowed Only get requests are allowed

Anything else can be done..

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to invoke the page as an Iframe from the Lightbox so it doesn't close automatically once the form is submitted.

Most lightbox plugins for Jquery give a parameter to launch it as an iframe.